# How to maximize utility using the Lagrange method

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

Is this solvable using the Lagrange method? If so, Does anyone know how to solve this using the Lagrange method? Utility is $a\ln x_1 + \ln x_2$. Budget constraint is $P_1x_1+P_2x_2= W$

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add a self-study tag.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your Lagrangian:

\begin{gather}
L(x_1, x_2, \lambda) = a ln x_1 + blnx_2 - \lambda(p_1x_1 + p_2x_2 - W)
\end{gather}

Derive your first order conditions:
\begin{gather}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} = \frac{a}{x_1} - \lambda p_1 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2} = \frac{b}{x_2} - \lambda p_2 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = p_1x_1 + p_2x_2 - W = 0
\end{gather}

Now you have your system of equations, which you can solve by yourself. Use the $\lambda$ from the first two conditions to get a relationship between $x_1$ and $x_2$, which you can then use on your third condition.